# How to make a custom directive configurable using services in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have built a custom a directive using angularjs. Now I have to make it configurable, so that who ever is using it should be able to call a service in my directive and initialize all the configurable parameters, I cant even get a big picture of what it is and how to make it configurable.
Right before any body uses my directive in their spa(single page application) they should configure the directive and then the configurable parameters should be set and the directive should function as configured.

Any help would be appreciated, please ask any questions if I am not clear because as said even I don't have a clear picture of what is needed. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the angular service providers and config functions, made another js file isolated all the configurations into the file. 
Just have to set the parameters in the config function, via the provider function we can inject the configurables into the desired controller.